# Unfold animation on DIV with Oridomi (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oridomi

I'm using the Oridomi (oridomi.com) Javascript plugin to achieve a paper folding animation. Specifically, I would like to have a div unfold on page load (picture a book opening).

However I am having difficulty getting the unfold() method to work, despite being a method which can be called on with the plugin.

You can see from this [example](http://owengot.com/unfold/index.html), that I can only get the div to fold back, rather than unfold from a folded state (in effect, I would like the animation to be reversed).

My javascript function -

```
(function(){ function init(){

var $domi = $('.unfold').oriDomi({ vPanels: 2, hPanels: 1, speed: 500, shading: false });

setTimeout(function(){
$domi.oriDomi('reveal', -90);
}, 600);}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

})();
```

And CSS -

```
.unfold {
    font-family: "Abril Fatface", "Hoefler Text", Constantia, Palatino, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 10rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #ff676d;
    background-color: #6ac1ff;
    padding: 2.5rem 0;
}
```

The documentation on http://oridomi.com is not very clear on how this can be implemented. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Oridomi does not supports reverse you have 2 options. One would be to know the END stare and `domi.oriDomi('reveal', 0);`. The other would be to reverse it first on a speed of 0 and then reveal at 0deg to unfold. Here is a fiddle with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Av6cD/2/

```
(function fold() {

    var $domi = $('.unfold').oriDomi({
        vPanels: 2,
        hPanels: 1,
        speed: 500,
        shading: false
    });

    $domi.oriDomi('reveal', -90);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $domi.oriDomi('reveal', 0);
    }, 1000);

})();
```

Please note that even if this is a nice effect, oriDomi is making a really mess to your DOM. CSS shaders would be the way to go once they get proper support.